# Does anyone know how to get the value of edittext from one activity to a textvew in another using a button?

Tags: android, android-intent

**GET EDITTEXT INPUT TO TEXTVIEW IN ANOTHER CLASS USING A BUTTON**

I am fairly new to android and I am trying to use an edittext to get user input on one screen (Activity), actually not just one edittext a few like a couple edit texts and maybe a spinner, kind of like a create a new user screen.  But I know how to use a button to getText() and setText() from the edittext to the textview if they are in the same activity but can not find anywhere how to accomplish this. Here is something like what the first class's bare bones would be:

```
public class UserInput extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I know the magic will be in the onClick(View v){} method, but what magic exactly do I use to 1-open a new Activity that houses the textview and 2- open the Activity?
Here is the second Activity for visual reference:

```
public class GetText extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
}
```

Again please if anyone can even chop up the code I will use just trying to get it to work right now.  Hopefully everyone can rally and give their input as to help others out that may be stuck as well.  Thanks ahead of time.

---

Here is what I have and if force closes on me:

Main Activity:

```
package com.mandam.ok;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

    public class UserInput extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText edit = (EditText)            
                            findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserInput.this, GetText.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.mandam.ok.GETTEXT",                         
                            edit.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Second Activity:

```
package com.mandam.ok;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetText extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("com.mandam.ok.MAIN");
        //edit.setText(view.getText());
    }
}
```

I will even attach my xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Second xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mandam.ok"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".OkActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GetText" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.mandam.ok.GETTEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now I know I am missing something very simple, just don't know what. I appreciate the help so far. :)

Comment: I don't think I understand. So, your main Activity has an EditText. Do you want to get this EditText's text into a new Activity and load it into the new Activity's EditText?

Comment: No if you look at activity two it is a text view.  I want to get user input from an edit text and put that input into a textview on a seperate activity, kind if one was setting up an account for yahoo mail, that person has a from to fill out name, address, password, etc. then that person clicks on a submit button and on the next page all that info is shown , something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second activity HAS a textview... saying that it IS a textview is wrong since Activities are not Views.

Here's how you can pass arguments to a new Activity... this code would be in your first Activity's onClick:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Intent intent = new Intent(UserInput.this, GetText.class);
intent.putExtra("com.package.name.NAME", edit.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

where "com.package.name" is your package name. An intent is an abstraction that performs an operation. In this case, the intent tells android to create a new Activity. The putExtra method allows you to put extra information into the intent before telling Android to create a new Activity. When you put an extra variable into an intent, you need to give it a unique string identifier that preferably starts with the package name.

Once the other Activity is created, here's how you can retrieve the string:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("com.package.name.NAME");
// do whatever you want with name
```

Comment: Hi ok now I am sorry Im such a noob but I tried that and my application will force close as soon as i try and open it I am going to attach all the code exactly as I have to show you what I have:

Comment: aleph_null, Ok I have provided the code I have while incorporating your code in it and it force closes can you shed a little more light on that. thanx

Comment: @mandam: In your first Activity, you are putting a string with identifier `com.mandam.ok.GETTEXT`. However, in your second Activity, you are attempting to retrieve a string with identifier `com.mandam.ok.MAIN`. These identifiers need to match up or else you'll get an error. A less important change is that you don't have to define `EditText edit` twice. Just doing so inside onClick is fine.

Comment: aleph_null,  ok I foudn why it was force closing the main activity was not defined but i fixed that and fixed my string identifier but it still does not show the text that is input into the edit text on the next activity.

Comment: @mandam: Are you calling `view.setText(name);`? If so, what is the value of name after calling `getStringExtra`? I recommend reading up on debugging as well as the Log function to help you solve these types of issues.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping someone coudl tell me what I was doing wrong so I can learn from my mistakes.  Like I said no one could answer this question in any other forum as well.

Comment: WOW,  I was not aleph_null.  I prodvided you with the wrong code I am so sorry you are absolutely right.  It works using:

Comment: sorry I wasnt finished but yes it works and I can't believe it took this long to figure out someting as basic as setting the wrong value.  Anyway thank you soo much for being patient and helping me out, I guess in the future I will make sure to be more specific and provide the right code to show what I am doing wrong, that is why I had problems with other forums as well.  Again big help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: aleph_null, sorry one more thing how do I do this for two edit text's and to two text view's?   Like:

Comment: OK yes excellent wow I can't believe how this held me up, I should know this basic stuff by now, I was over thinking everything.  Again thank you very much, I tried clicking the answer useful arrow but I don't have enough reputation yet, I will when I am able to. One more thing what is the deal with all these people editing my posts and such????

Comment: No problem mandam. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark underneath the voting arrows. People usually just change minor formatting issues. For instance, they often put backquotes (`) around inline code segments to make them stand out. They shouldn't ever change anything significant.